# Error 2025 when trying to removeChild, child not contained where it was added?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, removechild, addchild

I am trying to code a tile-based level editor, in which the Main class adds Tile class instances as children of the 'tiles' movieclip when clicking/dragging the mouse. 
I am able to add tiles to the container, and they show on stage, however I cannot remove any tiles when erasing them is enabled. It gives me the following error

```
Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
        at Main/Draw()
        at Main/::Go()
```

Also, when I check if the tile is inside the tiles container, it tells me that the parent is null.

So, a little help? I tried checking other questions with similar issues but none seemed to be close to mine.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    //import flash.events.TimerEvent.updateAfterEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        //containers
        var lines:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var tiles:Sprite = new Sprite();

        // Grid data
        var tileW:int = 20;
        var tileH:int = 20;
        var gridW:int = 20;//(inputWidth);
        var gridH:int = 20;//(inputHeight);
        var gridX:int = 50;
        var grixY:int = 50;
        var level:Array;

        //Drawing variables
        var go:Boolean = false;
        var erase:Boolean = false;

        var default_tile:int = 1;
        var type:int;

        var rect:Object = {x:100, y:50, width:(gridW * tileW)/100, height:(gridH * tileH)/100};

        //menus
        var sizeMenu:SizeMenu = new SizeMenu();

        var current:Tile = new Tile();

        public function Main():void {

            //Flash alignment and resizing
            stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align=StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            stage.addChild(lines);
            lines.x = rect.x;
            lines.y = rect.y;

            stage.addChild(tiles);
            tiles.x = rect.x;
            tiles.y = rect.y;

            stage.addChild(sizeMenu);

            stage.addChild(current);
            current.x = 50;
            current.gotoAndStop(default_tile);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Go);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Go);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, Go);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, ToggleErase);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, ToggleErase);

            Setup();

        }
        //Draws grid lines
        private function Setup():void {
            trace("Drawing Grid...");
            // create an empty array
            level = new Array(gridH);
            for (var i=0; i < gridW; i++) {
                level[i] = new Array(gridW);
            }

            // attach lines to create a grid
            for (var k=0; k <= gridH; k++) {
                var line = new Line();
                line.name = "line"+k;
                line.scaleX = rect.width;
                line.y = tileH * k;
                lines.addChild(line);

                for (var j=0; j <= gridW; j++) {
                    line = new Line();
                    line.name = "line"+j+"_"+k;
                    line.scaleX = rect.height;
                    line.x = tileW * j;
                    line.rotation = 90;
                    lines.addChild(line);                   
                }
            }
            type = default_tile;
            trace("Done drawing grid!");
        }
        //Decided if drawing is possible
        private function Go(e:MouseEvent):void {
            if (e.type == "mouseDown") {
                go = true;
                Draw(e);
            }
            if (e.type == "mouseUp") {
                go = false;
            }
            if (e.type == "mouseMove") {
                if (go) {
                    Draw(e);
                }
                //e.updateAfterEvent();
            }
        }
        //Toggles erase
        private function ToggleErase(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            if (e.shiftKey){
                erase = true;
            }
            if (e.type == "keyUp"){
                erase = false;
            }
        }


        // attaches the tiles when drawn on the grid
        public function Draw(e:MouseEvent) {
            var x = mouseX;
            var y = mouseY;
            var cx = Math.floor((x - rect.x) / tileW);
            var cy = Math.floor((y - rect.y) / tileH);



            if (cx >= 0 && cx < gridW && cy >= 0 && cy < gridH) {
                var target = e.currentTarget;
                if (!erase) {
                    if (tiles.contains(target)){
                        trace("Contained!");
                        tiles.removeChild(target);
                    }

                    var tile = new Tile();
                    tiles.addChild(tile);
                    tile.name = ("t_" + cy + "_" + cx);
                    tile.x = (tileW * cx);
                    tile.y = (tileH * cy);
                    tile.gotoAndStop(type);
                    level[cy][cx] = type;

                } else {
                    if (tiles.contains(target)){
                        trace("Contained!");
                        tiles.removeChild(target);
                    }

                    level[cy][cx] = default_tile - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        //Cleans the grid and redraws it
        private function ResetGrid():void {
            level = null;

            //Delete tiles
            while (tiles.numChildren) {
                tiles.removeChildAt(0);
            }
            //Delete lines 
            while (lines.numChildren) {
                lines.removeChildAt(0);
            }
            gridW=20;
            gridH=20;
            rect.width = (gridW * tileW)/100;
            rect.height = (gridH * tileH)/100;
        }
        // updates the current-clip
        private function update() {
            current.gotoAndStop(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue! All tile instances are given a name based on their position on the grid when added. Instead of making target the object the mouse was pointing at, I used getChildByName(); to search if there was already an object with a specific name, and to erase it if it did.

```
if (cx >= 0 && cx < gridW && cy >= 0 && cy < gridH) {
    var target = tiles.getChildByName("t_" + cy + "_" + cx);

    if (!erase) {
        if (target){
            tiles.removeChild(target);
        }
        var tile = new Tile();
        tiles.addChild(tile);
        tile.name = ("t_" + cy + "_" + cx);
        tile.x = (tileW * cx);
        tile.y = (tileH * cy);
        tile.gotoAndStop(type);
        level[cy][cx] = type;
    } else {
        if (target){
            tiles.removeChild(target);
        }
        level[cy][cx] = default_tile - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is causing the problem, basically you are calling `removeChild` twice for the same object.

```
 if (tiles.contains(target)){
     trace("Contained!");
     tiles.removeChild(target);
 }
 tiles.removeChild(target);
```

Comment: I am aware of that line. I left it there when replicating the error, because removing that line just prevents the error from showing, but doesn't removes Tiles at all.

Comment: Does it go into the if and trace `Contained`. If it is and there are no errors then it means it is removing it from tiles. Try debugging and see if the target is actually removed from tiles.

Comment: I did tried debugging several times. It does not trace nor it removes anything. It somehow seems flash adds the child to something else instead of the 'tiles' container.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I notice that you have the ability for the tile to be removed, and then try to remove it again at the end of this block :

```
        if (!erase) {
            if (tiles.contains(target)){
                trace("Contained!");
                tiles.removeChild(target);
            }

            var tile = new Tile();
            tiles.addChild(tile);
            tile.name = ("t_" + cy + "_" + cx);
            tile.x = (tileW * cx);
            tile.y = (tileH * cy);
            tile.gotoAndStop(type);
            level[cy][cx] = type;

        } else {
            if (tiles.contains(target)){
                trace("Contained!");
                tiles.removeChild(target);
            }
            // this is going to throw an error
            tiles.removeChild(target);
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You have them both wrapped in a conditional to tests if it's a child. Which line gets the error? I fail to see how you can get the error with that check.

Comment: Let me explain myself better: The conditional checking does not show an error, but it doesn't removes the target child either. It's like if the flash did nothing at all, because apparently the child is not in the parent to which it was added.

Comment: Maybe you should update the post with accurate information and a clear /concise account of what happens. First... Please go into your Publish Settings and enable "permit debugging" so that it'll give line numbers for runtime errors. Also, you should familiarize yourself with the debugger so that you can check the value of your variables as you step through code, so you can verify they have the values you assume they do.

Comment: Also, first thing you should verify in the Draw handler, is that the target is actually what you think it is. Is it even a tile ? Maybe it's a child of the tile ? On your tile, you should use `mouseChildren = false;` to avoid that.

Comment: All tile instances have a name based on their x, y position. Changing my code a bit. Maybe looking for the object by name can help.

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy on yourself and create a class for `Tile` with a `remove` method. Something like this:

```
class Tile extends Sprite
{
    public function remove():void
    {
        if(parent) parent.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

This way, you can simply do:

```
tile.remove();
```